# Is Chromedriver executing out of order with dynamic tables?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, dynamic, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to navigate to a user page by selecting the username on a dynamic table. Basically, first I search for the user, then after the filter is applied, I click the link on the table. This should take me to that user's page, but instead, it is taking me to the first user on the unfiltered table. I've even tried nesting my try/except/else statements, but I am still getting stale results.

Expected results: if searching for user_x, I will end up on user_x's authentication page

Actual results: If I watch the browser, I see it filter down to user_x's results, but I end up on user_a's authentication page. Note that search_results isn't even created until after the filter is applied.

```
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id('name').send_keys(user['username'].title() + '\n')

    except Exception as exc:
        print('Error searching for {}: {}'.format(user['username'].title(), exc), file=log)

    else:
        print('Filtered for user: {}'.format(user['username'].title()), file=log)

        try:
            name_filter = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'name_filter')))       

        except Exception as exc:
            print('Error searching for {}: {}'.format(user['username'].title(), exc), file=log)

        else:
            print('Filter successfully applied', file=log)

            try:
                search_results = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-hover']")))

            except Exception as exc:
                print('Error waiting for filter on {}: {}'.format(user['username'].title(), exc), file=log)

            else:
                search_results.click()

                try:
                    driver.get(driver.current_url + '/#authentication')

                except Exception as exc:
                    print('Error navigating to {}: {}'.format(driver.current_url + '/#authentication', exc), file=log)
                else:
                    print('On authentication page for {}'.format(user['username'].title()), file=log)
```

Comment: Well worded. The indicating what you have tried, what you expect and what you expect is an excellent format. While this isn't my area of expertise, it might help to show the code for the page that the chromedriver is interacting with. There are a few steps happening here so it would be good to show the results of the print statements for each step and what the relevant data/element contents are.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you really can't trust load sequencing in HTML. I got around this by doing a direct lookup on the username within the filtered table.

```
pause = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
search_results = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*/h4[contains(text(), '{} {}')]".format(user['first_name'], user['last_name']))))
```